# Subscribing to record changes in sharedDB cloudkit

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

It seems `CKQuerySubscription` cannot be used for subscribing to shared DB changes in cloud kit. `CKDatabaseSubscription` neither works nor does `CKSubscription`

How can I achieve subscribing to Shared DB changes?

Simply. How can i achive a notification about change made on record that is shared with me. **I AM NOT THE OWNER OF THE RECORD.**

Related question is here:

[How to receive cloudkit notifications about changes made on record shared with me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46784052/2725435)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, its not possible to subscribe on a zone level or a record level for Shared DB in CloudKit. Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1917/_index.html

```
Be aware that CKQuerySubscription is not supported in the shared database, and 
CKDatabaseSubscription currently only tracks the changes from custom zones in the private and shared database.
```

Comment: If this answer is accepted, why has it been down voted?

Comment: Well, I can't downvote on my own answer. Maybe the person was pissed at Apple/CloudKit Developer for not supporting it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It IS possible to subscribe on a zone level to a shared DB so the device with the shared DB will receive record change notifications. It is just not possible to query if the subscription has been set-up.

Comment: Umm, maybe it changed recently? Not saying that I'm correct, but I remember I couldn't get it to work. Anyway, will have to try Phil's recommendation yet.

Comment: @TheBasicMind, I would love to see code on how to subscribe if you can share.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for some time to successfully subscribe using CKDatabaseSubscription ***when the database had been shared with me***. It worked fine when I was the one sharing. The mistake I was making was that I was using the same subscriptionID in both cases. You need a unique subscriptionID if you want subscription to the shared database.

Comment: Ohh, so it is possible? Interesting. I will try that

Comment: Hmm... are you sure about that? I'm using the same subscriptionID to the shared database, and I have background push notifications flowing in both directions.